# PHP mail function on Google Cloud Compute Engine?

Tags: php, email-server, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, exim

I have a php website hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine. I also have a paid Google Workspace account for my emails, etc. I would like to use the mail function in php to receive emails from my contact form.

I tried following the steps here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

However, when I reached the "*Point your on-premise outbound server to Google*" section, I'm completely lost as none of the listed instruction sets seem to be for Google Cloud Compute Engine.

Is there a way I can get the mail function to work without having to tinker with third-party solutions?

Edit: I have Exim4 running on my server but don't know how to point it to my Google Workspace.

Comment: "Point your on-premise outbound server to Google" refers to **configuring your email client**, in this case your PHP code or the local SMTP server on your VM instance.

Comment: I have Exim on my server. How do I get the mail function to work with that? Most examples I find assume that I have a gmail address but it's my own domain.

Comment: It works exactly the same way, since your email is hosted with Google.

Comment: Same way as what? I'm a newbie at setting this stuff up and don't know how to get the mail function to work. Been researching and trying stuff all day and nothing's worked.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#Smarthost_with_Authentication

Comment: I don't feel safe putting my password in the file.

Comment: First, it's your server. Second, you need to read the directions again in the article you linked. You don't have to use a password. You can authenticate by IP address only.